# Описать void как тип responce d в YAML кодогенерации Swagger

Tags: java, post, swagger, yaml

У меня есть post запрос который ничего не должен возвращать. он передает body.
Описан у меня в yaml таким образом

```
/voidName:
    post:
      operationId: voidName
      tags:
        - voidName
      parameters:
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/postVoid'
      responses:
        200:
          description: ...
```

при кодогенерации у меня почему то для ответа формируется такой контракт

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postVoid",
            produces = { "application/json" }, 
            consumes = { "application/json" },
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    !>> Void removeCardAssoc(
            @RequestBody @Valid postVoid body)
```

что это за Void ? и как получить просто

void removeCardAssoc(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Void` есть такой [класс Void](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html)

Как раз используется при кодогенерации и рефлексии, обозначает специальный тип, который описывает отсутствие возвращаемого значения `void`

Например можно использовать так:

```
//проверка, что метод foo() возвращает void
if (getClass().getMethod("foo").getReturnType() == Void.TYPE) {
    //blah-blah
}
```